# Where do they get the power for drilling?

Tags: plot-explanation, escape-from-alcatraz

In Escape from Alcatraz (1979), How did Frank Morris get electricity to drill the iron bars at the top of the prison?

I saw this movie two times, still didn't figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

If you listen close at this point you are talking about in the movie Frank actually says there is an electrical outlet. This is around the 1:12 mark.

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed in the film when they look at [making the homemade drill](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=escape-from-alcatraz).

> **Frank:** *"We'll spread the bars with a pipe and knock the hood off."*
>
> ***"There's an electrical outlet here. Get a motor, a drill bit and a
> flashlight and we'd have it all."***
>
> ...
>
> *"Can you get me an extension cord and a drill bit from the shop?"*